# Genymotion resets GPS coordinates after restart

Tags: android, genymotion

I need test my app with different GPS coordinates. I use for this purpose Genymotion emulator. After each restart of emulator GPS widget state reset to OFF, and coordinates reset to default values. Why widget resets after restart? How I can save ON state and coordinates from prefious session?

Comment: Commercial version of the product remembers GPS values between restarts.

Comment: Maybe, this is limitation of trial version, but I didn't found it in official docs.

Comment: I also checked it happens same with me, I think this is because we don't have commercial version.